# How to change default database name BLUDB in IBM Db2 Warehouse on Cloud?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb

Whenever I create a Db2 service in IBM Cloud, it takes the default database name **BLUBDB**. I want to change to user specific name like TESTDB?

Comment: Why do you need this? There may be other ways to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Most of [service plans for Db2 Warehouse on Cloud](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/db2-warehouse) (formerly dashDB), then there is only a single database and the name is preset to BLUDB for simplicity. If you want to have more control, you could go with [Db2 Hosted on IBM Cloud](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/db2-hosted).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you are already locally cataloguing the database you could add an alias.

For example:

```
db2 catalog tcpip node mynode remote dashdb-myinstance.bluemix.net server 50000
db2 catalog database bludb as testdb at node mynode
```